# Which type of followers still benefit from Garrison mission XP?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Most of my followers are now level 100. I've currently got a mix of green, blue (rare), and purple (epic) followers. My question is: do they still benefit from Base XP or Bonus XP?

I've tried answering my question, firstly by using the in-game hints and common sense. Here's a typical scenario for my followers:

[image: garrison mission situation]

There's no real indication that *Ilona* would or would not gain the XP, but then again: what would she need it for? Your own character obviously won't get any XP from quests anymore, turning quest XP in gold if I'm not mistaken. However, there is even a "(+32)" in green mentioned, which is *not* mentioned for -say- *Hulda Shadowblade* (a rare/blue follower).

I've tried the ingame help as well, but it's plain awful ("garrison xp" yields zero results). I've skimmed and searched through [Wowhead's Garrison Guide](http://www.wowhead.com/guide=2456/guide-to-garrisons-in-warlords-of-draenor) but I can't quite seem to find my answer.

So, to summmarize:

- how does XP work for level 100 followers?
- how can you find out (is there any in-game clue to this)?
- does the rareness (green/blue/purple) of folllowers matter?
- does the level of the quest matter?

Comment: The +32 is just bonus EXP from having a better than 100 percent chance to complete the mission, or from follower abilities.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once a follower reaches level 100, any experience they gain from there goes into increasing their quality (green → blue → purple).

In-game, you can still see the XP bar on *non-epic* (green/blue) level 100 followers. See for example Songla and Hulda in your screenshot, which would have a bar like this:

[image: XP bar for blue follower]

Epic (purple) followers do *not* have such a bar anymore: they do not benefit from base or bonus XP at all. For example, your epic character "Ilona" will look like this:

[image: no XP bar for epic follower]

The green "+32 XP" in your screenshot is extra XP a character *would* get for being overqualified for a quest, but again: since your follower is already epic this XP will go to waste.

Higher quality followers have additional traits and abilities (which let them counter more stuff).

Comment: Makes sense. To verify then, there is absolutely no point in sending epic level 100 followers on XP missions? (Except for perhaps the achievements about number of quests completed.)

Comment: @Jeroen None at all. Only reason is if you need their traits or abilities and can't find them on a unit that still needs XP

Comment: @Psychemaster Or if you want the salvage crates

Comment: @Lyrion Unless I've missed a huge trick, sending out a level 100 epic unit doesn't give any more chance of a salvage crate than a level 100 uncommon or rare unit would. Unless you meant that sending an XP capped unit is better than not doing the mission (which is of course true)

Comment: @Psychemaster Yeah it was just, if you don't have any uncommon or rare 100 units left. If you don't have a salvage yard it is better to keep them. But if you do hava a salvage yard, then it is better to just send them on missions.

Answer (score 1):

I send my 100 level characters on XP missions just to clear out my available mission queue; rather than letting them all expire which seems to take longer.  I first do any armor upgrade missions, then resources (with Ben Gibb), then gold, then all the XP missions that are short duration (so I have followers available when the other missions are ready).  Chance of success is irrelevant so I just send anyone. Not sure this is smart but keeps me busy.